# Ansible - Create multiple folders if don't exist

Tags: ansible

Goal:

- Create multiple directories if they don't exist.
- Don't change permissions of existing folder
  Current playbook:

```yaml
- name: stat directories if they exist
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - /data/directory
    - /data/another
  register: myvar

- debug:
    msg: "{{ myvar.results }}"

- name: create directory if they don't exist
  file:
    path: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.path }}"
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0775
  loop: "{{ stat.results }}"
  when: not myvar.results.stat.exists
```

The `when` statement is wrong.

I looked at [the example provided](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html). But this only works for a single folder.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Using Ansible modules, you don't need to check if something exist or not, you just describe the desired state, so:

```yaml
- name: create directory if they don't exist
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0775
  loop:
    - /data/directory
    - /data/another
```

Comment: This will change the permission of the folder to root:root. I don't want to change the user/group if folder already exist.

Comment: Then specify the desired permissions for each folder.

Comment: Hmm... So what I desire isn't possible in Ansible?

Comment: It is possible and you can easily do it by fixing one line in your code, the question is if you should be doing this. As of now, you have publicly asked a question giving a specific use case and my public answer for this use case is: you should use Ansible as a declarative language.

Answer (score 35):

## Ansible - Creating multiple folders without changing permissions of previously existing.

Working fine for me. Hope this works for you as well just try.

```
---
- name: "Creating multiple by checking folders"
  hosts: your_host_name
  tasks:
  - block:
    - name: "Checking folders"
      stat:
       path: "{{item}}"
      register: folder_stats
      with_items:
      - ["/var/www/f1","/var/www/f2","/var/www/f3","/var/www/f4"]
    - name: "Creating multiple folders without disturbing previous permissions"
      file:
       path: "{{item.item}}"
       state: directory
       mode: 0755
       group: root
       owner: root
      when: item.stat.exists == false
      loop:
      - "{{folder_stats.results}}"
...
```

Answer (score 12):

Starting from Ansible 2.5, `loop` should be used to iterate over a list, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops

As the Ansible `file` module is idempotent, you do not have to check if the folders already exist.

For example:

```
- name: create backup directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    owner: backup
    group: backup
    mode: 0775
  loop:
    - /backupdisk/certificates
    - /backupdisk/mysql
    - /backupdisk/wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```yaml
- name: Setting facts dirs
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    service_path: /opt/services/
    service_dirs:
      - some_dir1
      - some_dir2

- name: Check if directories exist
  ansible.builtin.stat:
    path: "{{ service_path }}/{{ item }}/"
  register: new_dirs
  loop: "{{ service_dirs }}"

- name: Print Varaibles debug dirs
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ new_dirs.results | map(attribute='item') | list }}"

- name: Create related directories
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.path }}"
    state: directory
    owner: user
    group: user
    mode: "0o755"
    access_time: preserve
    modification_time: preserve
  loop: "{{ new_dirs.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.path }}"
  when: not item.stat.exists
```