# Registering multiple variables in a loop

Tags: ansible

I have a variable yaml file:

```
---
apps:
  - client
  - node
  - gateway
  - ic
  - consul
```

and this task:

```
- name: register if apps exists
  stat: path="/etc/init.d/{{ item }}"
  with_items: apps
  register: "{{ item.stat.exists }}exists"
```

I need to end up with a variable for each app with a value of true or false whether the file exists or not:

```
clientexists = true
nodeexists = true
gatewayexists = false
icexists = true
consulexists = false
```

For some reason, the `item` and `exists` concat is not working.

How can I achieve that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out. While looping in `Stats.yml` then `msg` field will contain your desired output.

**Variables.yml** `Here we are defining variables`

```
---
apps:
  - client
  - node
  - gateway
  - ic
  - consul
```

**Stats.yml**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: Gathering facts
  vars_files:
  - /path/to/variables.yml
  tasks:
  - name: "Here we are printing variables"
    debug:
     msg: "{{apps}}"

  - name: "Here we are gathering stats and registering it"
    stat:
     path: "/etc/init.d/{{item}}"
    register: folder_stats
    with_items:
    - "{{apps}}"

  - name: "Looping over registered variables, Its msg field will contain desired output"
    debug:
     msg: "{{item.invocation.module_args.path}}: {{item.stat.exists}}"
    with_items:
    - "{{folder_stats.results}}"

...
```

`folder_stats` will contain whole result, for individually referring to single - single result You can use it like this in you playbook.

```
folder_stats.results[0].stat.exists 
folder_stats.results[1].stat.exists 
folder_stats.results[2].stat.exists 
folder_stats.results[3].stat.exists
```

Comment: How can I use `folder_stats` later on as a varible? I need to see for each app if it exists, how can I do that?

Comment: @Moshe Through out this playbook, you can use it like this `with_items:
    - "{{folder_stats.results}}"` for looping

Comment: While looping you will get such results in loop `ok: ,...
        "changed": false, 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "checksum_algorithm": "sha1", 
                "follow": false, 
                "get_checksum": true, 
                "get_md5": true, 
                "mime": false, 
                "path": "/etc/init.d/consul"
            }, 
            "module_name": "stat"
        }, 
        "item": "consul", 
        "stat": {
            "exists": false
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "/etc/init.d/consul: False"
}`

Comment: and `msg` field will contain you desired output you can have a look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186301/ansible-create-multiple-folders-if-dont-exist

Comment: But I need to be able to access each app individually, not with a loop. I need to be able to access the `nodeexists` on different places and I can't loop each time.

Comment: I don't need a message, I need a variable for each app. @Sahil Gulati

Comment: @Moshe For that purpose for individual accessing you can use it like this `folder_stats.results[0].stat.exists`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144164/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-moshe).

Comment: yes `client` would be `0`, `node` is `1`, `gateway` is `2` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144170/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-moshe).